# What is needed to get I²C working with Debian Jessie?

Tags: i2c, debian, rtc

I have a custom system running on a Raspberry Pi B+ V1.2, based on Debian Jessie (buildroot, systemd, udev) - **not Raspbian** - and a custom built 3.19.3 Kernel chainloaded by U-Boot and a custom `init` script *(you see I am not unfamiliar with Linux low-level stuff - although I have little experience with I²C under Linux)*.

Everything is working fine (including HDMI, USB, Ethernet), but I can't get I²C working (which I do need for a DS3231 RTC). Both `/sys/class/i2c-adapter` and `/sys/class/i2c-dev` remain empty no matter what I do and no `/dev/i2c*` device wants to appear.

Obviously `i2cdetect` aborts with an error, too, because the I²C devices are missing.

I guess it's some simple config I'm missing, but I can't find out what it is.

My bootloader `config.txt` contains only a few entries:

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
kernel=u-boot.bin
```

Relevant I2C Kernel configs:

```
cat .config  | grep -F I2C | grep -v "^#"
CONFIG_REGMAP_I2C=m
CONFIG_INPUT_AD714X_I2C=m
CONFIG_INPUT_ADXL34X_I2C=m
CONFIG_I2C=y
CONFIG_I2C_BOARDINFO=y
CONFIG_I2C_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=m
CONFIG_I2C_MUX=m
CONFIG_I2C_HELPER_AUTO=y
CONFIG_I2C_ALGOBIT=m
CONFIG_I2C_BCM2708=m
CONFIG_I2C_BCM2708_BAUDRATE=100000
CONFIG_STMPE_I2C=y
CONFIG_MFD_ARIZONA_I2C=m
CONFIG_I2C_SI470X=m
CONFIG_I2C_SI4713=m
CONFIG_VIDEO_IR_I2C=m
CONFIG_SND_SOC_I2C_AND_SPI=m
CONFIG_SND_SOC_PCM512x_I2C=m
```

Calling `modprobe i2c-dev` and `modprobe i2c-bcm2708` succeeds without any error message. Kernel log just says `i2c /dev entries driver`.

What am I doing wrong? Any additional module necessary? Some important line in `config.txt` missing? ...?

## Update

The problem probably is that in my case the Raspberry bootloader doesn't boot Linux directly. Instead, **U-Boot** is in between, which (1) doesn't care about the device tree settings of the earlier bootloader and (2) doesn't seem to support device tree overlays by itself. I opened [a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256264/27552) to perhaps solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your kernel supports device tree you just need `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231` in `/boot/config.txt`.

That should let the RTC work as it is accessed through the kernel.

If you want to access I2C devices from userland then you need `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` in `/boot/config.txt` and i2c-dev in `/etc/modules`.

Make sure `i2c_bcm2708` is not in `/etc/modules`.

Device tree will automatically load `i2c_bcm2708` (it will not load `i2c_dev`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't doubt it is correct what you say, but check my update in the question - in my case the problem is probably more complicated.

Comment: @UdoG I'm afraid once you diverge from the standard kernels all bets are off.  You need to hope that someone else who has done similar had the same problem.